# Vim on Mac OS X terminal

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, vim

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9 using Vim 7.4 and I'm looking to find a way to map the key combination behavior "option + delete" to delete a word backwards. Currently, this works on every app in the OS, except when running Vim in the terminal. "control + W" works in Vim and some apps but not in all of the ones I use.

Any help?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [vim wiki page on mapping](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) to learn more than you ever wanted to know about how to map keys in vim. To preserve your key mappings, open (or create) a .vimrc file in your home directory.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me, but I use iTerm2:

```
inoremap <A-Backspace> <C-w>
cnoremap <A-Backspace> <C-w>
```

I have a note near that in my config file that says Terminal doesn't allow you to map delete combinations; but since I haven't used the default Terminal in quite a long time I don't know if that's true anymore.

Comment: That goes into your .vimrc? I'm trying this in iTerm2, but still doesn't work. Do you have your "option" key as a meta?

Comment: Yes, it goes in .vimrc; and yes, I have Option as meta.

Comment: Still not working. I forgot to mention that I'm using a Macbook, and it only has a single delete key unlike the normal Apple keyboard.